# Redis Cache in a .NET framework 4.6.2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, redis-cache

I am trying to implement Redis Cache in a .NET framework 4.6.2 application.

Have installed Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis and StackExchange.Redis nuget packages and wanted to add Redis as caching provider in the app, by adding it in the services of Global.asax.cs

```
services.Add(typeof(IDistributedCache),new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions(){Configuration = "cluster-name", InstanceName = "instance-name"} ));
```

however I'm getting an exception

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The service type RedisCache is not supported.
Parameter name: serviceType'
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion how to sort it out.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.